# How to pass obsoletes=0 to yum or package modules in ansible

Tags: ansible

If there is nice ansible way to pass `--setopt=obsoletes=0` arg (or whatever arg) to `yum` or `package` modules?

Currently I have to use `command` task:

```
command: yum install -y --setopt=obsoletes=0 package-1.3.2.el7.centos
```

What produces warning:

```
[WARNING]: Consider using yum module rather than running yum
```

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look at the [yum module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/packaging/os/yum.py), I didnt see any ability to add a costume flag to this command ([only those detailed on this doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/yum_module.html)).

Further reading showed that you are able to change this option inside `yum.conf` file ([at redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories))

> ## obsoletes=value
>
> …where value is one of:
>
> 0 — Disable yum's obsoletes processing logic when performing updates.
>
> 1 — Enable yum's obsoletes processing logic when performing updates. When one package declares in its spec file that it obsoletes another package, the latter package will be replaced by the former package when the former package is installed. Obsoletes are declared, for example, when a package is renamed. obsoletes=1 the default.

So I suggest you create a new `yum.conf` file (or update en existing one on the host if you wish) that contains this parameter. Then use the `conf_file` parameter in the module.

Comment: I wanted to give a full explanation of how to approach this problems. My first  approach was reading the module code, and see of there is a way to append the desired flag. The module has a `yum_basecmd` var that is built along the way by the module flags.